# Vue remove class on route watcher

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, nuxt.js

I've come across a small problem with a mobile dropdown menu I have in a Vue build. I am using max-height transition to animate the dropdown on a click event of hamburger icon. Works as expected but my issue is when I click to a different page route the page route changes and then this transition animation fires again. Is there a way to have the menu close without the transition on page route change? I'd like a cleaner change, click router > goes to page > menu closed without transition.

```
<!-- main nav -->
<ul class="row--flex main-navigation" :class="{ 'is-open': activeMenu }">
    <!-- nav item -->
    <li class="nav-item">Nav Item
    </li>
    <!-- nav item -->
    <li class="nav-item">Nav Item
    </li>
    <!-- nav item -->
    <li class="nav-item">Nav Item
    </li>
</ul>


export default {
  name: "Navigation",
  components: {
    Menu
  },
  data() {
    return {    
      activeMenu: false,    
    };
  },
 watch: {
    $route() {
      this.activeMenu = false;
    }
  }
};
```

css:

```
 .main-navigation {
    z-index: 2;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;

    width: 100%;
    max-width: 763px;

    @media (max-width: $mobileMax) {
      position: absolute;
      top: 100%;
      left: 0;

      overflow: hidden;
      align-items: flex-start;
      flex-direction: column;

      width: 100vw;
      max-width: 100vw;
      max-height: 0;
      margin: 0 calc(-50vw + 50%);

      transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }
  }

  @media (max-width: $mobileMax) {
    .is-open {
      max-height: 273px; 
    }
  }
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that without adding an additional variable. For example, I think you could set a new variable `isNavigating = true` in the watcher. At that point you'd append a new class - 'is-navigating` - which would speed up the transition to 0s: `transition-duration: 0`. Haven't tested it, but it should work.

Comment: @Dan, I did try something very similar to this but the problem now was after the watch route change the class added to remove transition based on the data, in this case "isNavigating" is still applied to the menu so the transition is now removed completely. I'm wondering if there is a way to detect "after" route change and remove the class by setting the variable to false or null?

Comment: I see. If this is a _page_ component, then you have access to [navigation guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#the-full-navigation-resolution-flow) that come with Vue Router. You could try to use **beforeRouteLeave** to add the `isNavigating` class and then in **beforeRouteEnter** remove it if it exists. Depends on what's your navigation flow. If everything happens in a single component, then these hooks don't trigger.